# Error while using #define

Tags: c++

I have defined a function not in class

```
#define BlendLight(b1, b2)  std::max(b1, b2)
```

then in the class I am trying to use it:

```
float someFunk(float x, float y)
{
 return BlendLight(x,y); //Error here - BlendLight marked red (
}
```

And I get Error: Expected an identifier

I am try to compile this in Visual Studio 2010
std::max()  header is included  / I have add algorithm but error still present (((

Comment: Is the compiler that picky, too?

Comment: Is the header file with `std::max()` included?

Comment: Is `BlendLight` defined in the same file as `someFunk`? If `BlendLight` is in a header file, do you include that header file?

Comment: If you replace `return BlendLight(x,y);` with `return std::max(x,y);` does the compiler complain?

Comment: above code is working fine on my system. Better if you can elaborate your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code isn't erroneous as it stands. Most likely you have forgotten to

```
#include <algorithm>
```

This is the header file where [`std::max`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) is defined.

Another possibility is that you didn't define `BlendLight` in the same file as the class where you want to use it. In that case you have to `#include` the header file where `BlendLight` is defined.

Apart from this, you should know that what you have defined is not a function, but a preprocessor macro. In C++, you should rather use a proper (maybe `inline`) function for this task, so that your compiler can do type checking:

```
#include <algorithm>
// ...
template <class T>
T BlendLight(T x, T y)
{
  return std::max(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nicklas. I am trying to "translate" an objective c project to c++ thath why I am doing the code close to original. Macros still not working (( even if I wrote <algorithm>. Perhaps I ll use your solution but as I suppose the macros in such signature could compare any numerical types not only float

Comment: @Papa: C++ has templates, this invalidates most use cases for macros. I updated the answer to allow any data type. As for your original problem: Did you define `BlendLight` in the same file where it is used? And, does replacing `BlendLight` with `std::max` in `someFunk` also give an error?

Comment: ohh.. you right. when I have change it to std::max it gived me error(. But I have add #include <algorithm> !

Comment: @Papa: Do you `#include <algorithm>` in the same source file where `std::max` is used and it yields an error? Which error?

Comment: Sorry, I have make a primitive mistake.. all workes like a charm. Thank you once more Niklas !

Answer (score 3):

Have you forgotten to add `/DNOMINMAX` to your command line when
invoking the compiler.  Historically, VS has defined min and max as
macros (and suppressed their definition in the standard header), in
`<windows.h>`, I think, and requires the above option in order to be
standards compliant.  (I've not checked whether this is still the case in VS 2010, since I always define this systematically.)

Answer (score 0):

You should better not be using macros for such definitions. It makes you horrible time when debugging it after some weeks.

Anyhow, have you included  ?

Comment: agree)) but see my comment for  Niklas Baumstark answer

Comment: @PapaJohn I see your point. Anyhow, if you agree with my posts please add me some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include `algorithm` before using `BlendLight(b1, b2)` because you used `max` which is available in algorithm library.

Comment: No, he should include `<algorithm>` before *using* `BlendLight`.